# PHP - Developing a filter form

Tags: php, mysql

I will briefly explain my situation.

I need to develop a filter form for the front end of my store, it will include 2 select elements. The first select element will include the Manufacturer of the vehicle, the second select element will include the Model.

The SQL data table is constantly changing every day, new cars come in daily and all vehicle data is placed in one table. One of the columns contains the manufacturer of the vehicle  and one contains the models however if I have two of the same vehicle their could be more than one 'BMW' string in the column. Each row is a vehicle just so you know.

I could just parse the column into the Manufacturer select element however if I do that I could be left with 7 Ford options and 4 BMW options, I only want one manufacturer string to show.

When the manufacturer has been selected I then need to parse only the models for that manufacturer that has been selected. I am unsure how I could do this part maybe I could parse only the column that contains the models of the selected manufacturer.

I have came up with this script however it just fetches every manufacturer string and displays duplicates...

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT manufacturer FROM vehicles GROUP BY manufacturer"); 

$results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<select name="manufacturer">';

foreach($results as $r)
{
echo '<option value="'.$r.'">'.$r.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Is there a way to stop duplicates in PHP so if there is a string that is a duplicate it will only display it once? I feel this would solve my problem.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

A Helpful query might be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(manufacturer) FROM vehicles
```

Comment: Would that stop duplicates?